# How to duplicate a selection and place it above or below the selection

Tags: vim, duplicates, selection

If I have something selected in Vim in visual mode, how can I duplicate that selection and place it below or above the selection?

Comment: you want to select same lines but above? or do you want to duplicate selection?

Comment: i want to duplicate selection

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Press <kbd>y</kbd> to yank what you've got selected visually, then <kbd>p</kbd> to paste below the cursor or <kbd>P</kbd> to paste above it.

And since you asked about pasting below the selection block, I'll copy what [michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/59592/michael) said below: After you <kbd>y</kbd> to yank, use <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>></kbd> to move it to after the selection block, and then <kbd>p</kbd> to paste.

Answer (score 10):

Since I do this a lot (select a block, yank, go to end of last visual selection, paste) I set up a visual block shortcut under <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (prior to this, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> seems to be the same as <kbd>j</kbd> in a visual block).

```
vmap <C-p> y'>p
```

Now it's just making a visual selection and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>.

Comment: I like to have an automatic line break between the selection and the duplicate: `vmap <C-p> y'>o<Esc>p`

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the <kbd>V</kbd>...<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> combo you might want to know about some jumps <kbd>'</kbd><kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>></kbd> to get to the last character of the previous visual mode text. Specifically, if you want to paste below you'd go <kbd>V</kbd>...<kbd>y</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>></kbd><kbd>p</kbd>. If it's a long multiline it may be handy.

It's one of those jumps you may find handy if you're doing this a lot.

Comment: that doesn't seem to work, do you press ' and then SHIFT+. to get > ?

Comment: i am actualy using a VIM plugin for Netbeans so this might be the problem

Comment: '> has 'not in vi' in the vim help so you'll be missing out on that one. 

:helpgrep not\ in\ Vi  yields 709 matches in the vim help. So you probably shouldn't confuse the two. Most emulators only cover the basics

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>y</kbd> to yank (copy) the selection into a buffer.

Use <kbd>p</kbd> to paste the selection where you want it to be.

Comment: using p for paste breakes the formating because it doesnt take the whole lines

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to copy/paste the whole line?  If so, get out of visual mode, then use <kbd>yy</kbd> to **y**ank the whole line, then <kbd>p</kbd> to **p**aste.

Comment: a) he didn't say it was a single line, and b) why get out of visual mode if you've already got it selected?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> which copies the current line, then <kbd>p</kbd> to paste.
- Make a selection, with <kbd>v</kbd> for example, then copy with <kbd>y</kbd> and paste with <kbd>p</kbd>.

Comment: using p for paste breakes the formating because it doesnt take the whole lines